# ag-grid - getColumnGroup() method returning null after hiding all columns in a group

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

In ag-grid I have a table with a structure like this:

```
            |   Temperature      |  ....
 -----------|------|------|------|---------
 Date       | min  | avg  | max  |  ....
 -----------|------|------|------|---------
 2017-03-01 | 19.5 | 20.2 | 22.0 |  ....
 2017-03-02 | 18.8 | 20.4 | 21.6 |  ....
```

I want to be able to hide the entire Temperature column group and I do it like this:

- get column group by it's name with `columnApi.getColumnGroup(groupId)`
- get column children with `getChildren()`
- loop through all elements and hide/show depending on Column visibility state

The hiding part works ok, but when I want to show the columns again, the `getColumnGroup` method returns a `null` object, and I cannot set the columns to be visible again. Any ideas?

The entire code (part of an Angular2 component) looks like this:

```
toggleColumn(groupId: string) {
    let groupColumn = this.dataGridOptions.columnApi.getColumnGroup(groupId);
    let children = groupColumn.getChildren();

    for (let idx = 0; idx < children.length; idx++) {
        let colId: string = children[idx].getUniqueId();
        let colState = this.dataGridOptions.columnApi.getColumn(colId);
        let colVisibility = colState.isVisible();

        this.dataGridOptions.columnApi.setColumnVisible(colId, !colVisibility);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't directly (explanation below).
what you can do is loop over ALL columns and get the parent and check that it matches the groupId.

take a look at following link :
https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/696

> the columns always exist, exactly one column for every column def. the
> column then has a 'visible' attribute.
>
> the groups are transient and only exists if they are needed (there is
> also the concept of 'OriginalColumnGroup' to keep track of what
> columns are in each group, but you don't have access to that, it's
> internal)
>
> [...]
>
> https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid-master-slave/index.php
>
> so, in summary, column groups only exists if the group is showing, and
> there can be multiple groups for the same group if the columns are
> split. so, that's why the column groups don't return if they are not
> visible!